# Tool to automate basic connectivity testing

Tags: networking

After our vendors have setup a certain test environment, we need to go in to perform connectivity testing between PC to servers and also between servers.

The problem is that we run a range of tests to telnet between 2 nodes on several ports and this is a manual and rather tedious process.

Does anyone know of a small tool or script that I can take input on the range of ports to be test and will run an automated range of testing against those ports? All I need to do is to validate whether a TCP connection can be established from the source PC / server to the target server IP address / port.

Thanks,
Wong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a portscanner like [nmap](http://nmap.org/)

You can use `-P` to specify individual ports, or ranges: `-P 25,80,110,1024-2048,3306`

Comment: Strictly speaking, nmap is the best fit for my use case, with one major problem: it's completely banned. I just spent the past couple of weeks trying to get an exception to the rule but failed. My client's IT security team is adamant that anybody using nmap is a threat to the network and refuses to compromise on this.

Answer (score 3):

The [netcat/nc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) and possibly [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) tools are good for this. With nc for example you can set a timeout and then interrogate the exit status of the command

```
nc -w 1 example.com  80
```

would return an exit status of 0 after 1 second if a connection can be established and 1 if a connection cannot.

Answer (score 0):

For a long term monitoring you should use nagios. You could also configure notifications and escalations when something fails.

www.nagios.org

Comment: I'm more looking for a basic shakedown tool that will be removed as soon as the work is done. Nagios is more of a long term solution which doesn't fit this scenario as well.